# is split always internally sorting the resulting data frames

Tags: r

I just wondering if I can be sure that split() is always sorting the results?
What is the rule for the sorting?
The example works, but I haven't found the according line in the help pages. Sorry if I misread the help.

```
 dat.exmpl <- data.frame(cbind(a=11:20, b=rep(3,10)), fac = c(2,1))
 split(dat.exmpl, dat.exmpl$fac)
 dat.exmpl <- data.frame(cbind(a=11:20, b=rep(3,10)), fac=rep(c("blueb","bluea")))
 split(dat.exmpl, dat.exmpl$fac)
```

ExtraQ: Is there a way to remain the order which is supplied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort order of `split` is the factor order of your grouping variable.  So, if your grouping variable is a factor, then the levels of that factor are kept intact.

An example: modify your data so that `fac` has the levels `c("blueb","bluea")`:

```
dat.exmpl <- data.frame(
  a=11:20, 
  b=rep(3,10), 
  fac=factor(rep(c("blueb","bluea")), levels=c("blueb","bluea"))
)
```

Then the results of `split` are in the same order as the levels of `fac`:

```
split(dat.exmpl, dat.exmpl$fac)
$blueb
   a b   fac
1 11 3 blueb
3 13 3 blueb
5 15 3 blueb
7 17 3 blueb
9 19 3 blueb

$bluea
    a b   fac
2  12 3 bluea
4  14 3 bluea
6  16 3 bluea
8  18 3 bluea
10 20 3 bluea
```

Comment: Thanks good answer. However, can you explain more in detail what "factor order of your grouping variable" means? Does split() internally coerce the grouping variable into factors? and what is the normal sort order of that? For numeric variable this is obvious but for characters I am not sure why it is sorting "blueb" before "bluea". does it really sort according to the string?

Comment: If the grouping variable is already factor, then `split` doesn't do any sorting. In my example, `blueb` is before `bluea` because that's how I defined the factor levels, i.e. that's the point of my example. In summary: `split` doesn't do any sorting. If it seems like sorting is happening, it's because of the way `factor()` deals with the factor levels (usually lexicographically sorted). For more detail, see the help for `?factor`, in particular the `levels` argument.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. However, I meant the sorting of split if you do NOT use factors (as in my originally example). Am I right that split does internal coercing of the grouping variable to a factor where the sorting happens?